# Postfix very slow delivery

Tags: postfix, dovecot, amavis

I installed postfix + dovecot + mysql + amavisd + spamassasin. Everything works fine (mail is sent and received) except that the received mail stays too long in the queue (for about 15 minutes) before it gets to the user mailbox. If I run

```
# postsuper -r ALL && postfix flush
postsuper: Requeued: 1 message
```

the message is immediately removed from queue and successfully sent to the user mailbox.

The content of /etc/postfix/master.cf file is

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter= 
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
smtp-amavis  unix  -    -       y       -       2       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
  -o smtpd_bind_address=127.0.0.1
  -o smtpd_helo_required=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o disable_vrfy_command=no
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
vacation    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/var/spool/vacation/vacation.pl -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

and the output of "postconf -n" is

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 2048000000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 204800000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = ubiqom.eu
myhostname = mail.ubiqom.eu
mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
         permit_mynetworks,
         reject_unauth_destination,
         reject_non_fqdn_sender,
         reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
         reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
         reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
         reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
         reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/mail.ubiqom.eu.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/mail.ubiqom.eu.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf,                     regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 101
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:101
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you trace what happens to it in the log (`/var/log/mail.log`)? You can trace job IDs there.

Comment: message logs please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - wrong socket file used in amavis configuration, thus causing messages to be deffered.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can also accept your own answer and I suggest to do that (clicking the pipe icon on the left side).